# Pylint errors with @validator decorator from AWS Lambda Powertools Python

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, pylint

I'm getting some Pylint errors while using the [Lambda Powertools for Python](https://awslabs.github.io/aws-lambda-powertools-python/latest/). If I download the three files from the [Validator decorator example code](https://awslabs.github.io/aws-lambda-powertools-python/latest/utilities/validation/#validator-decorator),  and run `pylint --errors-only validator_decorator.py`, I get three errors:

```
************* Module validator_decorator
validator_decorator.py:5:1: E1120: No value for argument 'handler' in function call (no-value-for-parameter)
validator_decorator.py:5:1: E1120: No value for argument 'event' in function call (no-value-for-parameter)
validator_decorator.py:5:1: E1120: No value for argument 'context' in function call (no-value-for-parameter)
```

Here is the code from `validator_decorator.py`:

```
from aws_lambda_powertools.utilities.validation import validator

import schemas

@validator(inbound_schema=schemas.INPUT, outbound_schema=schemas.OUTPUT)
def handler(event, context):
    return event
```

Despite the errors, the code works just fine, but I'd like to understand if I'm doing something wrong. I could always add a `# pylint: disable=no-value-for-parameter` but I'd rather not if there's a better way to handle this. I've tried digging through [the source](https://github.com/awslabs/aws-lambda-powertools-python/blob/develop/aws_lambda_powertools/utilities/validation/validator.py#L12) but there's a lot of wrapping going on there, and since I'm at the level of just having read [Primer on Python Decorators](https://realpython.com/primer-on-python-decorators/) I could use a hand understanding this. Thanks.

```
(venv) $ python --version
Python 3.9.10
(venv) $ pylint --version
pylint 2.12.2
astroid 2.9.3
Python 3.9.10 (main, Jan 15 2022, 11:40:53) 
[Clang 13.0.0 (clang-1300.0.29.3)]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the function documentation [here if you click "expand source code"](https://awslabs.github.io/aws-lambda-powertools-python/1.14.0/api/utilities/validation/index.html), one of the suggestion of use is this:

```py
from aws_lambda_powertools.utilities.validation import validate

def handler(event, context):
    validate(event=event, schema=json_schema_dict)
    return event
```

There are other suggestions, but non where it's used as a decorator, maybe it's not supposed to be used as one.

Comment: I wish the decorator style didn't have this problem, but this way would accomplish the goal of getting rid of the pylint errors, thanks.